# How to add a logo (that links) on top of a slider?

Tags: html, css, slider

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#slider').cycle({

        fx: 'scrollHorz',

        speed: 'slow',

        timeout: 5000,

        next: '#next',

        prev: '#prev'

    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #wrapper {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        height: 250px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #container {
        overflow: auto;
    }
    #slider {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 250px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
    }
</style>
</head>
<a name="top"></a> 
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="container">
                    <div id="slider">
                        <img src="slideimages/bookline.jpg" width="100%" height="250" alt="flight-1">
                        <img src="slideimages/fam.jpg" width="100%" height="250" alt="flight-1">
                        <img src="slideimages/houseog.jpg" width="100%" height="250" alt="flight-1">
                        <img src="slideimages/skyline.jpg" width="100%" height="250" alt="flight-1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Where in here should I add my logo so it will be able to be visible at the top with the header and also the ability to be a link?

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with z-index. This is a css styling option which allows you to place divs, paragrapsh, etc over each other.

You can experiment with it on following link: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex)

This is providing you btw a good example of what you want I think?

W3schools [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) isn't the best site around but it can get you far, providing you a lot of properties.

So create a div between your slider tags an use z-index on it.

I hope this helped you around!

Comment: I know about the z index, what I want to know is where in there should I place my image code?

Comment: If edited my comment: So create a div between your slider tags an use z-index on it.

Comment: between or outside the slider tags?

Comment: You need to put it between the slider tags

Comment: that makes it kind of glitchy... it would go away and the logo would be there, then it would scroll in and wash the logo away...Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of it?
If I'm not wrong you need to put the z-index property on both div-containters

Comment: I decided to leave the logo for a 50px tall head div where I can too include a search form but leave the slider beneath it... I feel like it was the right choice

Answer (score 0):

As you are going to switch it to fixed position, you can insert it right inside the wrapper. It'll need fixed positioning and higher z-index than the container. It's a common practice to add top-margin to the container with the same amount as the fixed item's height.

Comment: **css**:
`position: fixed;

top: 0;

left: 0;

right: 0;

height: 60px;`

Comment: it worked... but apparently the slider does not allow transparent images?

Comment: I switched the transparent logo also and it now scrolls with the screen?